# jQuery & PHP: encode and decode filename

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I use jQuery sortable for images so I need to save filename to li id like this:

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li id="myfile.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

I need some crypt to encode filename with jQuery and then decode it in PHP.
I would use md5, but it's only one way...

Thank you

Comment: It would help to expand on why you need this? Is it for security, or some other reason?

Comment: why don't you use hidden input for storing file name?

Comment: md5 is not even safe.

Comment: It's a little bit complicated - I use uploadify so user can upload multiple files and then sort them. So I use sortable with filename which value is sended by hidden input by serialize method. It's not easy problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need a cipher, that could be decrypted only with a secret key or do you just want to change a filename to a unreadable string of alphanumeric characters? 
Second option is easier, you can use php functions: [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) and [base64_decodde](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php). 
If you want your file names to be unrevertable by others, you can use [mcrypt library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php), but it needs a little knowledge of [cryptography](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/Understanding-encryption-and-cryptography-basics) to do it safe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use built in php functions base64_encode('file_name.jpg') to encode the file name and base64_decode($encodedFileName) to decode the file name.

Please visit for more refrence.
for base64_encode()
  http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

for base64_decode()
http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.base64-decode.php